# PHP Arrays: How to get this hexadecimal value from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array, laravel-8

I have retrieved an array like this:

`echo "<pre>"; var_dump($trigger);`

And the result is:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#372 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x02"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#376 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x03"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#371 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x01"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#373 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "0x00a8"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#383 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0f"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#377 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0c"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#381 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x1b"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#380 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x05"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#367 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x16"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#418 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x17"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
  }
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#407 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x03"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#384 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x01"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#394 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x01"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#300 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x06"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#401 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x14"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#392 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x19"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#404 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x02"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#385 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x08"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#399 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0f"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#299 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0a"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
  }
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#370 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x04"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#376 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x03"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#375 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "0x01"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#398 (2) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "0x00a8"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(3) "gmp"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#396 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x05"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#378 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0a"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#379 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x0c"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#373 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x13"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#390 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x19"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(phpseclib\Math\BigInteger)#388 (2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "0x1c"
      ["engine"]=>
      string(3) "gmp"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to get the hexadecimal values (example: `0x02`, `0x03`, etc).

I have already tried `var_dump($trigger[1]->value);` and I got this:

```
object(GMP)#411 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
object(GMP)#382 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#409 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
object(GMP)#383 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#401 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#396 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#416 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#400 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#395 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
object(GMP)#381 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
object(GMP)#404 (1) {
  ["num"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

But it does not seem to be the hexadecimal value !

So how can I properly get the hexadecimal value from this `$trigger` array ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:**

If I say `var_dump($trigger[0][1]->value)`, I get this error:

> **Error** Cannot use object of type phpseclib\Math\BigInteger as array

**UPDATE #2:**

I'm using [Tron](https://developers.tron.network/) API to get access to all the [contract](https://tronscan.org/#/contract/TJCNRYmRUU3VWv7eNt1sArcqdutTiDKQTz/code) information. I can properly get all the tickets information and by using a `for loop`, I can get this array as result of each ticket.

The code behind for doing that goes here:

```
         try {
            $totalTck = $TransactionBuilder->triggerSmartContract(
                (array)$abi,
                $contractH,
                $function,
                $params,
                $feeLimit,
                $addressH,
                $callValue = 0,
                $bandwidthLimit = 0);

            // $totalMinus = ($totalTck[0]->value) - 1; 
            $totalMinus = 10;
            for($i=0;$i<=$totalMinus;$i++){
                $address = ADDRESS;
                $addressH = $tron->toHex($address);
                $contract = CONTRACT;
                $contractH = $tron->toHex($contract);
                $function="getTicketInfo";
                $params=array("0"=>$i);
                $feeLimit=30000000;
                $callValue = 0;
                $bandwidthLimit = 0;
                try {
                    $trigger = $TransactionBuilder->triggerSmartContract(
                        (array)$abi,
                        $contractH,
                        $function,
                        $params,
                        $feeLimit,
                        $addressH,
                        $callValue = 0,
                        $bandwidthLimit = 0);

                    var_dump($trigger[0][1]->value);
                        //$query = DB::table('tickets')->insert([
                        //    'userId' => '',
                        //    'types' => '',
                        //    'startRound' => '',
                        //    'endRound' => '',
                        //   'numbers' => $trigger[0]->value
                        //]);
                } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: have you looked up the docs for the BigInteger class you are using?

Comment: @Jhecht No, I don't think it's necessary for getting value of an array

Comment: This question needs more description. Where you are getting $trigger? If it is a collection of some model records? OR getting it from some API endpoint?

Comment: @sssurii I'm using tron api to get all the ticket information. Then by using a for loop I got access to each ticket, now I need to get this hexadecimal number and then convert it to decimal number, but now I'm stuck with getting hexadeciaml data: https://developers.tron.network/

Comment: Also you are trying `var_dump($trigger[1]->value)`, But as per your data $trigger array also has 2 subsets of collection. So I believe it should be like `var_dump($trigger[0][1]->value)`  given `value` property of model class `phpseclib\Math\BigInteger` is not protected .

Comment: @sssurii I tried it and it says: `Cannot use object of type phpseclib\Math\BigInteger as array`

Comment: Thanks for the information, can you please this in your question too? It will help to understand your question clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232893/discussion-between-kkk-kkk-and-sssurii).

Comment: Which API endpoint you are using from https://developers.tron.network/

Comment: you are accessing the array correctly from what I can tell; you should check the biginteger documentation from there.

Comment: @KKKKKK.instead of var dump can you print_r and post data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`BigInteger`](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php) class
has a `toHex()` method. So you can get the hex value like this:

```
echo '0x'.$trigger[0]->toHex();
```

You can iterate over the `$trigger` array like this:

```
foreach($trigger as $e)
{
    if(is_array($e))
    {
        foreach($e as $t)
            echo '0x'.$t->toHex().'<br>';
    }
    else
        echo '0x'.$e->toHex().'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You are right Oliver, but you are echoing `$trigger[0]` as a Hex value, I have to put this syntax inside of a for loop like this: `for($i=0;$i<=$totalMinus;$i++){`. So in this example, at least 10 Hex values should be appeared (because `$totalMinus = 10;`). How to do that ?

Comment: @KKKKKK It's a simple array iteration. See my update.

Comment: I tested and got: `Call to a member function toHex() on array`

Comment: The interesting part is that `echo '0x'.$trigger[0]->toHex();` works fine but `foreach($trigger as $t) { echo $t->toHex(); }` returns error!

Comment: I just noticed that `$trigger` had a subarray. See my update.

Comment: You did it man, YOU DID IT :))) Thank u, I wished I could hug you :D

Comment: One more question man, why did u put `0x` behind the `$t->toHex()`:  `echo '0x'.$t->toHex().'<br>';` What is the reason for adding that ?

Comment: @KKKKKK It's the usual prefix for hex numbers, but of course you can remove it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest to your loop (i.e. for, foreach) to iterate through the array, instead of accessing item using the numeric index like:

```
foreach ($trigger as $item) {
  $item->value;
}
```

Now Look at the class property you are trying to access: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php
Here Value property is private. look line: 70
Now try to access `value` through available public method returning `value` property.

```
foreach ($trigger as $item) {
  $item->toString(); 
 //OR
  $item->toHex();
}
```

If you want fix no. of iteration then you can `for` loop like:

```
$totalMinus = 10;
for($i=0;$i<=$totalMinus;$i++){
    $trigger[$i]->toHex();
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function toHex() on array

Comment: Call to a member function toString() on array